# Can I map my Mac keyboard shortcuts to match windows?

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Is their a way that I can GLOBALLY map my keyboard shortcuts on my Macbook pro to match windows shortcuts? (Cut, Copy, Paste, Beginning of Line, End of Line, etc...) I go through spells where I am switching between the two and have been doing so for at least 3 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OSX 10.7 Lion (probably the same under 10.6):

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard tab -> Modifier Keys

Remap command to ctrl, ctrl to command

That should get you close, although if you ever let anyone else use it, they may get a bit confused if they're expecting the defaults.